# A trigonometric identities with the ratio of four terms like $1+(\frac{\tan x}{\sin y})^2$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove:
$$\frac{1+\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sin y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sin z}\right)^2}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\tan y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\tan z}\right)^2}$$

I started by opening the brackets and squaring but did not get the required answer.

Comment: Protip: More people will respond to your posts if you format them properly, a.k.a learn mathjax.

Comment: Don't square anything. Let sin x=A, cos x=B, sin y=C, cos y=D. Then tan x=A/B and tan y=C/D. Simplify each side and then use $ B^2=1-A^2$ and $D^2=1-C^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, the given equality can be easily proved by simplifying $LHS$  $$LHS=\frac{1+\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sin y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sin z}\right)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin y\cos x}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin z\cos x}\right)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2z(\sin^2 y\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)}{\sin^2y(\sin^2 z\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2z((1-\cos^2 y)(1-\sin^2 x)+\sin^2 x)}{\sin^2y((1-\cos^2 z)(1-\sin^2 x)+\sin^2 x)}$$

$$=\frac{\sin^2z(1-\cos^2 y-\sin^2 x+\sin^2 x\cos^2y+\sin^2 x)}{\sin^2y(1-\cos^2 z-\sin^2 x+\sin^2 x\cos^2 z+\sin^2 x)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2z((1-\cos^2 y)+\sin^2 x\cos^2y)}{\sin^2y((1-\cos^2 z)+\sin^2 x\cos^2 z)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2z(\sin^2 y+\sin^2 x\cos^2y)}{\sin^2y(\sin^2 z+\sin^2 x\cos^2 z)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2z\sin^2 y\left(1+\frac{\sin^2 x\cos^2y}{\sin^2 y}\right)}{\sin^2y\sin^2 z\left(1+\frac{\sin^2 x\cos^2 z}{\sin^2 z}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{1+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\tan^2 y}}{1+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\tan^2 z}}$$

$$=\frac{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\tan y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{\tan z}\right)^2}=RHS$$

Comment: Use `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` your answer looks  messy.

Comment: @Nikhil: I think every step in the answer is clear. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric functions for each angle can be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin^2 x &=& \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} &\quad \tan^2 x &=& \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \\
\sin^2 y &=& \frac{\gamma}{\gamma + \delta} &\quad \tan^2 y &=& \frac{\gamma}{\delta} \\
\sin^2 z &=& \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + \zeta} &\quad \tan^2 z &=& \frac{\epsilon}{\zeta} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The trigonometric identity can then be rewritten as:

$$
\frac{1 + \frac{\alpha (\gamma + \delta)}{\beta \gamma}}{1 + \frac{\alpha (\epsilon + \zeta)}{\beta \epsilon}}
\stackrel{\text{?}}{=} \frac{1 + \frac{\alpha \delta}{\gamma (\alpha + \beta)}}{1 + \frac{\alpha \zeta}{\epsilon (\alpha + \beta)}} \\
$$

After expanding the fractions within fractions, we have:

$$
\frac{\beta \epsilon (\beta \gamma + \alpha (\gamma + \delta))}{\beta \gamma (\beta \epsilon + \alpha (\epsilon + \zeta))}
\stackrel{\text{?}}{=} \frac{\epsilon (\alpha + \beta) (\gamma (\alpha + \beta) + \alpha \delta)}{\gamma (\alpha + \beta) (\epsilon (\alpha + \beta) + \alpha \zeta)} \\
$$

After cancelling the obvious factors, we have:

$$
\frac{\beta \gamma + \alpha (\gamma + \delta)}{\beta \epsilon + \alpha (\epsilon + \zeta)}
\stackrel{\text{?}}{=} \frac{\gamma (\alpha + \beta) + \alpha \delta}{\epsilon (\alpha + \beta) + \alpha \zeta} \\
$$

After expanding the parentheses and ordering to be soft on the eyes, we have:

$$
\frac{\alpha \delta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma}{\alpha \epsilon + \alpha \zeta + \beta \epsilon}
= \frac{\alpha \delta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma}{\alpha \epsilon + \alpha \zeta + \beta \epsilon} \\
$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Suggestion/anecdote: When I demonstrate this type of approach (working both sides of an identity simultaneously) on a chalkboard, I replace the "$=$" with "$\stackrel{\text{?}}{=}$" (that is, `$\stackrel{\text{?}}{=}$`) as I go, because I'm asking, *"Are these equal?"* In the final step, I used to replace the "?" with "!" (*"These are indeed equal! Hooray!"*); however, since programming languages tend to use `!=` for "is not equal" (what's up with that?), I now opt for a smiley face: $\stackrel{\stackrel{\bullet\bullet}{\smile}}{=}$ (`$\stackrel{\stackrel{\bullet\bullet}{\smile}}{=}$`).

Comment: @Blue, thanks for the suggestions, I've removed some imagination and adopted your equal-question mark. When the two sides are actually equal though, I think it's fair to just use $=$ or maybe use $\equiv$ that I've sometimes seen for identities. What do you think?

Comment: +1. Looks good to me! (Decorating the final equality tends to work best with a live audience. :)

Comment: Incidentally, since *everything* is squared here, all those exponents amount to nothing more than visual clutter. It's harder to motivate in the beginning, but you *could* just assign $$\sin^2 x = \frac{a}{a+b} \qquad \tan^2 x = \frac{a}{b} \qquad \cdots$$ and make the simplifications far softer on the eyes. (Hey ... You just *doubled* trigonography.com's Twitter following! :)

Comment: @Blue, thanks again for another great suggestion. I would not have thought about simplifying that way this time but I certainly hope to notice the pattern next time. (trigonography.com is the first Twitter feed I follow! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin z}\right)^2}=\frac{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan z}\right)^2}$$

$$\iff\frac{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin y}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan y}\right)^2}=\frac{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin z}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan z}\right)^2}$$

So, if we can prove that $\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin A}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan A}\right)^2}$ is independent of $A$, we are done.

**Method** $\#1:$

$\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin A}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan A}\right)^2}=\dfrac{1+\tan^2x\csc^2A}{1+\sin^2x\cot^2A}$
$=\dfrac{\cos^2A+\sin^2x(1+\cot^2A)}{\cos^2x(1+\sin^2x\cot^2A)}=\sec^2x$ which is clearly independent of $A$

**Method** $\#2:$

$\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin A}\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\tan A}\right)^2}=\dfrac{(\sin^2A\cos^2x+\sin^2x)\sin^2A}{\sin^2A\cos^2x(\sin^2A+\cos^2A\sin^2x)}=\sec^2x$ as $\sin^2A\cos^2x+\sin^2x=\sin^2A(1-\sin^2x)+\sin^2x=\sin^2A+\sin^2x(1-\sin^2A)=?$